# Show message when a Group contains no elements in a Grouped ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've implemented a **Grouped ListView** which contains two groups, which works according to James Montemagno's blog post on the subject: [Enhancing Xamarin.Forms ListView with Grouping Headers](http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping).

Opposed to James' example, I must show all possible groups (which, in his example, would be something like all groups from A to Z).

One of those groups is **empty** and I'd like to show a message with something like "There are no Monkeys for this Group".

This is straightforward with non-grouped ListViews, but I have no idea how to achieve this when Grouped is Enabled.

I don't think adding my code here will make any difference, but... Let me know if I'm wrong. :)

--
Edit #1:
I'm using a particular DataTemplate for this list (a frame with same labels and an image) which would be unsuitable for showing just a message to the user.

Comment: D you want to show the "no monkeys" text in the group header or in an item below the group?

Comment: @hvaughan3 an item below the group.

Comment: I think it might help to see your code, specifically how you are gathering the data that you want in the `ListView` but an idea that comes to mind would be to simply gather all your data, then insert a single item for each empty group with the text you want to show, in the case it would be `"There are no " + groupName + " for this Group"` or something like that. Would that work for your implementation? It would require you to know all possible groups before hand.

Comment: I updated my question, but I got it working while trying to simplify my code to create a decent example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While creating a code example, I managed to get it done by adding a **IsEmpty** property to the Grouping class:

```
public bool IsEmpty { get { return Items.Count == 0; } }
```

The ListView's **GroupHeaderTemplate** looks like this (simplified):

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Label IsVisible="{Binding IsEmpty}" Text="This group is empty." />
                  </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```